# gensim.LDAMulticore throwing exception:

Tags: python, gensim, multicore, lda

I am running LDAMulticore from the python gensim library, and the script cannot seem to create more than one thread. Here is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 97, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamulticore.py", line 333, in worker_e_step
    worker_lda.do_estep(chunk)  # TODO: auto-tune alpha?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 725, in do_estep
    gamma, sstats = self.inference(chunk, collect_sstats=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 655, in inference
    ids = [int(idx) for idx, _ in doc]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 812, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 765, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 325, in _handle_workers
    pool._maintain_pool()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 229, in _maintain_pool
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 222, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I'm creating my LDA model like this:

```
ldamodel = LdaMulticore(corpus, num_topics=50, id2word = dictionary, workers=3)
```

I have actually asked another question about this script, so the full script can be found here:

[Gensim LDA Multicore Python script runs much too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431187/gensim-lda-multicore-python-script-runs-much-too-slow)

If it's relevant, I'm running this on a CentOS server. Let me know if I should include any other information.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory` sounds like you are running out of RAM.

Check your available free memory and swap.

You can try to to reduce the number of threads with the `workers` parameter or the number of documents to be used in each training chunk with the `chunksize` parameter.